# BSOD after hardware and software install

Tags: windows-7, ssd, bsod

I recently changed from an HDD to an SSD to resolve some lagging issues I was having. Very frequent stuttering. Anyway in the process of changing over there was some issues with my file system on the new drive, so I downloaded a tool called "IObit Unlocker". When running it to delete some locked folders, it crashed my computer with a bsod, and when I started it back up again it had told me that the CPU overheated. Understandable so I deleted the software, and didn't worry about it. There was however some issues when I booted back up, the first thing I noticed was that the links in my taskbar were all blank images, and no longer opened to the correct location, just prompting me to delete them. I still had the software that was tied to it (chrome/steam etc.) but the taskbar links no longer works and had to be remade. Now I've gotten a few BSOD's since then, and that was just yesterday. Did I delete an important folder and corrupt my OS? is there some other issue? I've attached what I believe to be the correct dmp file (my minidump folder is empty) could someone maybe decypher what is causing these?
[DMP file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qoefyrsx1ec7w9z/MEMORY.DMP?dl=0)
Thanks,

Comment: How did you clone your HDD to SSD?

Comment: Tried a bunch of different methods and then eventually gave up and started from scratch, moved over a couple documents manually. No cloning.

Comment: So what was the cause of “file system” issues and the desire to delete “locked” files on a fresh system? You need to update your question with this info. You said you copied over a couple documents manually but yet you refer to broken taskbar links. How is it possible you have any taskbar links on a fresh system you only copied a couple of documents to? Right now it’s not clear what you actually did and what the problem is.

Comment: I made the taskbar links manually. I decided to delete the folders because I thought they served no purpose, they were hidden folders as far as I could tell didn't contain any information.

Comment: Hidden folder often contain the most important things. You can’t see the contents of hidden folders unless you show hidden items. Additionally, even more critical files may be marked as “system” files and won’t show up unless you also show system files. If it’s not too inconvenient the best course of action is to start fresh again and stay as far away from IObit as possible. Newly installed systems don’t have “file system” issues.

Comment: That was the backup plan, going to see if anyone has any insight on the dmp files first, thanks though!

Comment: Ok. You can analyze this yourself with WhoCrashed. It’s important to take all dumps in to consideration. Not just one.